# Can we find the regression coefficient a if we don't have the means of x and y?

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation

I am given the value of regression coefficient 'b',a 'x' value and its corresponding 'y' value.Can i get 'a'  by the equation a=y-bx or it can only be used when we have the means of both the variables?

Comment: If you have all the x-y pairs that is all you need to get the least squares estimates for the slope and intercept. You don't need to be given b,

Comment: No,i don't have all the pairs.i am given only one pair of x and y.

Comment: Okay then you can clearly get a from the equation a=y-bx using the observed x-y pair and b. In this case you would need to know b.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the regression framework a is an intercept derived from minimization of a set of variables from their mean plus an error structure. clearly a in your equations $a=y-bx$ requires some sort of error term which implies we cannot get a.

Unless... the only formulation of calibration to the regression model prescribed was using the lone x and y values you were given. Then just shove your numbers into the equation and voila :)

Comment: This was a multiple choice question and one of the options is "the given information is insufficient to find a ".Could that be the correct choice?

Comment: Sounds good to me :) As a side note, it is perhaps better to be more open with your question and provide us keen answer-ers the most ifnformation possible. Tell us it was multiple choice! :)

Comment: The error term doesn't enter the equation. It would only enter when the true values for the slope and intercept appear in the equation. That is the form of the model.